# How to sort spring data jpa repository on character varying column

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

Hi we are using postgress database and spring data jpa repository in java to use the data. Now we have one column (version) of type "character varying (255)" and column have data as `val1 = 11.0.2000.78` and `val2 = 11.0.2000.301`

when we fire sort descending query using spring data jpa repository it lists value `val1` above the `val2`. Actually it should list `val2` above the `val1`.

We understand that since column is of type character it is considering 7 greater than 3 so is the issue. Any solution for this ?

We want numeric sort on the column of type character on such values. Is there any way to handle in spring data jpa repository ?

Comment: Yo can use a function to split the parts of the column and then sort these parts independently. There are various string functions in postgres. Have a look https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE tableone
(
    test text
) ;


INSERT INTO tableone(test) VALUES('11.0.2000.78');
INSERT INTO tableone(test) VALUES('11.0.2000.301');


select * from tableone order by test desc;

SELECT
   test
FROM
    tableone order by 
    ( CAST(
        COALESCE(
            NULLIF(
                replace(test, '.', ''), 
                ''),
            '0') 
       AS numeric) ) desc;
```

Comment: Thanks  Amit this works directly when i fire it on database, but since we are using jpa specification i cannot write custom query there like you mentioned. So i am thinking of implementing sorting List<Class> by one of its variable in java side. if you have any heads towards it please suggest

Comment: JPA supports native query. (Sorting in server memory is not the most efficient way. For e.g. what if you need top 5 records based on certain sort. You would end up fetching all records in memory.)